# QFileDialog::selectFile() and auto scroll to view selected file

Tags: qt

After selecting a file in `QFileDialog` with `selectFile()` the selected file is not automatically visible in the viewport. Is there any way of automatically scrolling the so that the the (first) selected file is visible?

Answer (score 2):

Based on how the `selectFile()` function is implemented I don't see it as being possible.  The way to go around it might be subclassing `QFileDialog` to reimplement `selectFile()` to get the position of the file you are selecting and scroll the horizontal and vertical scrollbars to it.

The only problem is that the `UI` is implemented in the `QFileDialogPrivate` class which has `QFileDialog` as a friend so this may not work but you can try it to be sure.